# AngularJS: $broadcast from service not always call listeners on child controllers

Tags: angularjs

I have a service to connect with my server and after I get data I broadcast event:

```
 user.getUserData = function () {
                var userData = $http.get('/user');

                userData.success(function (data) {
                    currentUser = data
                    $rootScope.$broadcast(EVENTS.userChanged);
                });

                userData.error(function () {
                    user.removeUser();
                });

                return userData;
            };
```

I have also one main controller set on body tag and few child controllers. On that controllers I have

```
$rootScope.$on(EVENTS.userChanged, function () {});
```

and this function on the main controller is called every time I refresh the app but on the child controllers is called only sometimes. What can be wrong?

Comment: The `$broadcast` may be fired too early, the child controllers haven't been initialized yet.

Comment: You need to show more code. Likely your routing setup, and where your child controllers are instantiated.

Comment: I think @runTarm has right, but what can I do to be sure that my child controllers are initialized?

Comment: I'm not sure but shouldn't you put your .$on on respective scopes, instead of $rootScope ?
You broadcast event from $rootScope, which sends it down, but i'm not sure how handling such event on $rootScope would look like.
I have broadcast on set on rootScope in my app, and then im handling events (.$on() ) in their respective scopes, and i never noticed any problems...